How to Handle Angular NgZone with Playwright?
Unable to interact with Buttons , Dropdowns..etc through Playwright when my Angular application running with ngzone. Suggestions please
Tried using angular stabilization :
await page.waitForFunction(() => (window as any).getAllAngularTestabilities().every(testability => testability.isStable()));
but it did not work.

Please share a [mcve]--package.json, full simple app, and complete, runnable testing code. Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
